# Sum of the roots equation

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Need help!

how to prove that equation have two roots on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$
and calculate $x_1+x_2$

$$\tan(x)^{\cos^2x}=\frac{\tan(x)^{\sin^2x}}{e}$$

That's what I tried :

$ \tan(x)=t $

$\cos^2x=\frac{1}{1+t^2} $

$\sin^2x=1-\frac{1}{1+t^2} $

And have to solve :$$ \frac{\ln(t)}{1+t^2} = (1- \frac{1}{1+t^2})\ln(t)-1$$

Comment: Is that an epsilon in the denominator?

Comment: could you  format a little bit?especially first equation

Comment: i think there is natural $e$

Comment: Since the question is about the sum of the solutions, I am inclined to believe that we are not supposed to find the actual solutions, but there has to be way to get to the sum without finding solutions.

Comment: Thats true, I need to show that there are two roots on the interval and calculate only the sum

Answer (score 1):

Big hint:  there are lots of identities connecting the trig functions of $\theta$ to those of $\pi/2 -\theta$.

This hint does not tell you how many roots there are, however.

Comment: Let me "expand" the hint to show how big it really is :) Suppose that $\theta$ is a root, and then show that $\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$ is also a root.

Comment: Additional hint: Rewrite your nice equation as $\ln t=1+\frac{2}{t^2-1}$ and let $f(t)$ be the left side minus the right. Differentiate and **simplify**. You will find the increase/decrease behaviour is very nice up to the singularity at $t=1$, and also after. That gives a count of the roots.

Comment: thanks for the hint, but more important for me is how to find the $x_1+x_2$